# Rule of thumb for deciding between "description" and "memo"?

Tags: accounting

I'm new to accounting software.
I've been going through some of my old statements and entering them into an accounting system.

Because I don't really have any experience with this, I've been having trouble deciding what to put in the "description" and what to put in the "memo".

My question is, is there rule of thumb or well-known "good practice" for deciding what to put in which section? For example, should confirmation IDs be in the memo section or the description?  How about the name of the sender or recipient (for transfers)? What about account numbers? etc.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: @BenMiller: Bank of America's online "portfolio" manager (manual account).

Comment: Does the software's help offer any guidance about how they expect you to use these fields?

Comment: @keshlam: Not that I've found...

Comment: This might be a better question for the support staff of the software vendor. The answer will probably be subjective anyway.

Comment: @JohnFx: I don't understand. Memos are in every accounting software I've seen. How is this software-dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found works for me and is consistent with how the software otherwise works:

- Description describes **what** happened -- e.g. you paid Bob's Shop in New York $5
- Memo describes **why** it happened -- maybe it was for a snack, maybe it was to settle a debt

So that means confirmation IDs and such would all go in the description.